# Primary Key Join Column with Spring MVC and Hibernate Annotations

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, hibernate-annotations

can anyone help me with this little problem for me? (My question is in the bottom)

**Author class**

```
import javax.persistence.*;  

@Entity  
@Table(name="authors")  
public class Author {  

@Id  
@GeneratedValue  
private Integer id;  

private String name;  

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn  
private Biography biography;  

// Getters and Setters  

}
```

**Biography class**

```
import javax.persistence.*;  

@Entity  
@Table(name="biographies")  
public class Biography {  

@Id  
@Column(name="author_id")  
private Integer authorId;  

@Column(name="information")  
private String information;  

// Getters and Setters

}
```

**Main class**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();  
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    session.beginTransaction();  

    Author author = new Author();  
    author.setName("Jack London");  

    session.persist(author);  

    Biography biography = new Biography();  
    biography.setInformation("Jack London was an American author...");  
    biography.setAuthorId(author.getId());  

    author.setBiography(biography);  

    session.save(author);  

    session.getTransaction().commit();  

    session.close();

}
```

But i want to apply this relationship to this architecture: I using Hibernate-Annotations with Spring-MVC and JSP for the view. My source code is as follow:

**AuthorDao>AuthorDaoImpl (BigraphyDao>BigraphyDaoImpl is same)**

```
// imports

@Repository("authorDao")
public class AuthorDaoImpl implements AuthorDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public void createAuthor(Author author) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(author);

}

@Override
public Author updateAuthor(int id) {
    return (Author) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Author.class, id);

}

@Override
public void deleteAuthor(int id) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("DELETE FROM Author WHERE id="+id).executeUpdate();

}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Author> readAuthors() {
    return (List<Author>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Author.class).list();

}
}
```

**AuthorService>AuthorServiceImpl (BiographyService>BiographyServiceImpl is same)**

```
// imports

@Service("authorService")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class AuthorServiceImpl implements AuthorService {

@Autowired
private AuthorDao authorDao;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public void createAuthor(Author author) {
    authorDao.createAuthor(author);     

}

@Override
public Author updateAuthor(int id) {
    return authorDao.updateAuthor(id);

}

@Override
public void deleteAuthor(int id) {
    authorDao.deleteAuthor(id);

}

@Override
public List<Author> readAuthors() {
    return authorDao.readAuthors();

}

}
```

**Author Controller (Biography Controller is same)**

```
// imports

@Controller
public class AuthorController {

@Autowired
private AuthorService authorService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/saveAuthor", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveAuthor(@ModelAttribute("command") Author author, BindingResult result) {
    authorService.createAuthor(author);     
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/createAuthor.html");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/createAuthor", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView createAuthor(@ModelAttribute("command") Author author, BindingResult result) {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("authors", authorService.readAuthor());
    return new ModelAndView("createAuthor", model);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/updateAuthor", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView updateAuthor(@ModelAttribute("command") Author author, BindingResult result) {
    // does not matter the content here     
    return null;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteAuthor", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView deleteAuthor(@ModelAttribute("command") Author author, BindingResult result) {
    // does not matter the content here
    return null;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/readAuthors", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Author> readAuthors(){
    return authorService.readAuthors();
}
```

**JSP form**

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/app/saveAuthor.html">
  <p>
    <form:label path="name">Titulo:</form:label>
    <form:input path="name" value="${author.name}"/>
  </p>
  <!-- here is the problem with the biography values-->
  <p>
    <button type="reset" >Reset</button>
    <button type="submit" value="Save" >Save</button> 
  </p>
</form:form>
```

How can i send values (author name and biography information) from my jsp form to its respective tables in my database. Please if you need more details just ask me.

Comment: What happens when you press Save? Are you seeing an error?

Comment: Hi @WillKeeling, i don't see errors but i can't save values in the second table(empty biography table). I think i'm missing something in the form respective to the biography paths. I don't know how to set the biography paths.

Answer (score 0):

To add the biography information, it should just be a case of adding the respective fields to the form for the `biography` nested object - using dot notation in the path.

Also note that the `<form:input>` tag doesn't take a `value` attribute. Spring will set the value automatically.

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/app/saveAuthor.html">
  <p>
    <form:label path="name">Titulo:</form:label>
    <form:input path="name" />
  </p>
  <!-- Biography information -->
  <p>
    <form:label path="biography.information">Biography:</form:label>
    <form:input path="biography.information" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="reset" >Reset</button>
    <button type="submit" value="Save" >Save</button> 
  </p>
</form:form>
```